# PayPal Checkout UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY: COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal checkout in my angular website. the integration seems to be fine but I always have an error when creating an order. Below you will find all the code I used.

**index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY-APP-SANDBOX-ID"></script>
</head>
```

**donation.component.ts**

```
declare var paypal;
...
export class DonationComponent implements OnInit{
    ...
    ngOnInit(): void {
        ...
         paypal.Buttons({
             createOrder: (data, actions) => {
                 return actions.order.create({
                     purchase_units: [{
                         description: "Donation For Al-Darb Platform.",
                         amount: {
                             currency_code: 'USD',
                             value: this.value
                         }
                     }]
                 });
             },
             onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
                  const order = await actions.order.capture();
                  console.log(order);
             },
             onError: err => {
                 console.log(err);
             }
         }).render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

**donation.component.html**

```
...
<div #paypal></div>
```

After executing everything works fine only on checkout (after log in to Paypal and validating the payment). I always got the following error **HTTP 400**:

```
{
    ack: "contingency",
    contingency: "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY"
    data: {name: "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY", details: [{ issue: "COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION" ...}],
    ...
}
```

Comment: "COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION" ...}],..."  This is not a technical issue. What other details are you hiding behind those ...'s ?  What is the country of the receiving PayPal account?

Comment: ... = "The API cannot complete the requested action, or the request action is semantically incorrect or fails business validation."

Comment: and for the country it's Algeria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION

There should be more information like a debug_id you can share, but since it's Algeria I'm sure the issue is the account needing an auto-sweep method set up in order to receive payments.

You can read the [PayPal Receive Funds and Automatic Transfer Agreement for Algeria (country code `dz`) here](https://www.paypal.com/dz/webapps/mpp/ua/recpymt-full) (other applicable countries on its list have their own URL but agreement text is likely the same)

As detailed there, possible auto-sweep methods include an international bank account, or a local Visa card that is able to withdraw funds (not all cards can do so).

Once you have this set up on the account, you'll be able to receive payments. If it's a live account, contact PayPal's support for any further assistance, as it's not a technical issue for Stack Overflow.

**If this were a sandbox mode account**: simply [create a sandbox business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Faccounts) for a different country such as US to use when testing your integration.