# Paypal sandbox account response fails on server

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm new to paypal and sandbox, however the algorithm works fine with my on the localhost,
whereas it fails to complete the transaction on remote, I'm using php laravel

the algorithm on my paypal controller :

```
 $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = [
         "intent" => "CAPTURE",
         "purchase_units" => [[
             "reference_id" => rand(000000,999999),
             "amount" => [
                 "value" => number_format($amount, 2, '.', ''),
                 "currency_code" => \App\Models\Currency::findOrFail(get_setting('system_default_currency'))->code
             ]
         ]],
         "application_context" => [
              "cancel_url" => url('paypal/payment/cancel'),
              "return_url" => url('paypal/payment/done')
         ]
     ];

    try {
        //ddd($request);
        // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
        $response = $client->execute($request);
       // ddd($response);
   

        // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
        return Redirect::to($response->result->links[1]->href);

    }catch (HttpException $ex) {

    }
```

When I dump the response it's as :

```
PayPalHttp\HttpResponse {#2005 ▼
+statusCode: 201
 +result: {#2012 ▼
 +"id": "29F719283B401012X"
 +"intent": "CAPTURE"
 +"status": "CREATED"
 +"purchase_units": array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1944 ▼
    +"reference_id": "481922"
    +"amount": {#1948 ▼
      +"currency_code": "USD"
      +"value": "150.00"
    }
    +"payee": {#1975 ▼
      +"email_address": "sb-adxtx19866369@business.example.com"
      +"merchant_id": "MUJ4QB7EWSWDJ"
    }
  }
]
+"create_time": "2022-08-30T10:04:38Z"
+"links": array:4 [▼
  0 => {#1949 ▼
    +"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/29F719283B401012X"
    +"rel": "self"
    +"method": "GET"
  }
  1 => {#2017 ▼
    +"href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=29F719283B401012X"
    +"rel": "approve"
    +"method": "GET"
  }
  2 => {#2010 ▼
    +"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/29F719283B401012X"
    +"rel": "update"
    +"method": "PATCH"
  }
  3 => {#2009 ▼
    +"href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/29F719283B401012X   /capture"
    +"rel": "capture"
    +"method": "POST"
    }
  ]
 }
```

}

and The Exception i get :

```
PayPalHttp\HttpException
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":   [{"issue":"COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION","description":"Transaction cannot be processed due to a possible compliance violation. To get more information about the transaction, call Customer Support."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"a548bb80c1863","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

I've tried multiple ways to resolve it like :
1- Changing the sandbox account region from EGY to US.
2- Changing the entire paypal account.

I would appreciate a little assistance here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you read [this Paypal document](https://www.paypal.com/sg/webapps/mpp/ua/recpymt-full). You need an auto-sweep method, as in an international back account or a local Visa card that MUST be able to withdraw funds. However you should take this up with Paypal support, instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783745/paypal-checkout-compliance-violation

Comment: Auto-sweep method ? WHAT IS IT ? PLEASE

Comment: A PayPal feature, it automatically moves ('sweeps') money in your Paypal account to your bank account. " There is a feature called Auto Sweep that checks daily and automatically “sweeps” any money that arrives in your PayPal account into your bank account overnight." [Source](https://www.mymoneyblog.com/how-to-enable-auto-sweep-paypal.html)

Comment: But there's no real money floods between, I'm testing things in a developer mode . Do I still need to have bank account to get stuffs done ?

Comment: And what's wired to me is that, under localhost environment it's working like a charm. but on server things gets messy ??

Comment: Well to comply with Paypal, probably. I haven't worked with Paypal sandbox in a while, so not sure. I'm guessing those rules and regulations apply to anything, also the developer sandbox, but unsure.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

> COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION

For sandbox testing: the **receiving** business account should *not* be from [one of the countries listed here](https://www.paypal.com/eg/webapps/mpp/ua/recpymt-full). So, it should work if you try again with e.g. a US receiver account (payer/sending account does not matter)

In the live environment: [this answer has more details on the set up needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783745/paypal-checkout-compliance-violation) to receive payments in one of those countries with auto withdrawal to a card or bank.

Answer (score 0):

After a long debugging, the thing turn out to be after the payments. nothing wrong with paypal.
I debugged untill I found the payment status "`completed`"
After the payment, I update my DB records.
in laravel I used `findOrFail($id)` method which turns out to be the problem
It fails to find the record, I don't know why however this terminates the logic.

thank you guys.