# How to store custom data related to order on PayPal

Tags: python, json, paypal, sdk

I'm new to Paypal API. I wants to save a JSON on the PayPal so that I can get it as response after capturing PayPal order. I'm using PYTHON
Data I want to store is array of products.

```
products = [
       {'id': 'id_1', 'price': 100, 'quantity': 2},
       {'id': 'id_2', 'price': 50, 'quantity': 2}
]
```

After searching I came to know about application_context parameter in paypal. I'm storing my data in JSON like this and sending it to **/v2/checkout/orders** to get **order ID**

```
paypal_json = {"intent": "CAPTURE", 
    "purchase_units": [{"amount": {"currency_code": CURRENCY, "value": total_price}}],
    'application_context': {"products": products}}
```

I'm trying to get **application_context** using PayPal API by this but it does not contain my **application_context** data.
[PayPal Orders_Get API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get)

```
access_token = generate_access_token()
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
response = requests.get(f"https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{order_id}", headers=headers)
print(response.json(), response.status_code) # it does not contain application_context
```

Right now I'm using client-side localStorage. But client can easily change that data after approval of order and data sent to me can be updated one for which client didn't even paid. And that will get stored in Database. That is why I need a secure way to store data related to order. I can use server to created order and store it in database with orderID of paypal and mark it as uncomplete until it is approved. But that will be waste of memory if client will not approve order.
That is why I wants to know how can i store my products data on PayPal and retrieve it after capturing of order. Can anyone please help me?

I have tried to send get request to PayPal API to get order data but it does not contain application_context which I added in JSON while creating PayPal order

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I don't know. I thought I had to approve that edit. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application_context parameter is deprecated, do not use it. Also even before it was deprecated, it was never used to store product information.

Product information belongs inside the `items` array within each purchase_unit. See the [create order API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) for details.

Item information will be visible during order approval, and stored in the transaction record in [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) . However, it is not returned in API calls.

You should store item information in your own database records.

To reconcile your own order records with PayPal captures, you can set an `invoice_id` parameter for the purchase_unit. The invoice_id value should be unique, never before used for a captured transaction on that account. Duplicate capture attempts are blocked.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm thinking of using orderID of PayPal as primary key for my order in database. And then using it to approve order in database after capturing of PayPal Order. Do you think it is good idea? And should I use it as invoice_id?

Comment: Better to generate your own sequential ID, with a meaningful prefix if you have more than one store/outlet. It is possible to use the PayPal order ID if your system is incapable of that, but the PayPal Order ID is for the approval process only and will not be persisted or visible in the transaction record, account interface, or reports.

Comment: I see! One of the biggest problem for me is that PayPal does not work in my country. So there is not any way for me to do experiments and check things and how they actually work. So invoice_id is the ID which will be provided to payer when they pay?

Comment: invoice_id would be the same ID you use for your own records, yes, as long as it's unique (never used for a successful capture on the PayPal account before). Everything can be tested in the PayPal sandbox environment, the country you are in should not mater

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: **The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation, CODE: 422** POST /v2/checkout/orders/{ORDER_ID}/capture. Does that mean I can't complete transaction with sandbox account?

Comment: Not enough information (request and response bodies) to say what the issue is

Comment: I'm trying to capture PayPal order which is approved on frontend using sandbox personal account. Sending POST request to **/v2/checkout/orders/{ORDER_ID}/capture**. It does not have any request body as I'm following this [PayPal Capture Order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture). But it is returning JSON with error that **The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation, response CODE: 422** [Response Body](https://gist.github.com/ShailMurtaza/7954bbdffce733c41f4e5db6fbbd6a5d)

Comment: Okay, a COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION, likely due to the country of the account.  Assuming this is sandbox, create a new sandbox Business account for a different country such as US. For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783745/paypal-checkout-unprocessable-entity-compliance-violation